# Should equations be formatted in scientific notation?

Tags: mathematics, writing-style, formatting

I have an equation that has very small coefficients (f(x) = -0.000014x4 + 0.000044x + 0.002782) should I put the whole thing in scientific notation, or can I leave it as-is in a paper? Thanks.

Comment: Why not replace f(x) with g(x), where g(x) is a suitable power of 10 times f(x)?

Answer (score 4):

The specific publication you are submitting your paper to may have specific rules for formatting. If not, **be consistent** and use your consistency to maximize clarity. Is it crucially important that your reader understand the difference between 0.002782 and 0.000278? If so, scientific notation may be helpful. Otherwise, all those extra zeroes may be fine where they are.